# How to run CMD commands in powershell without escaping special chars?

Tags: command-line, powershell, escape-characters

I am trying to use `PowerShell` as my default shell, instead of `cmd`.

But some trivial cmd commands are pre-processed by powershell and broken, for example:

```
PS C:\git\myproject> git stash show stash@{0}

Too many revisions specified: 'stash@' 'MAA=' 'xml' 'text'
```

Here, the `{0}` is replaced by Powershell to something else.

What is the more practical way (i.e. with the least amount of escaping effort) way to launch `CMD` commands without PowerShell pre-processing?

Right now I am using

```
PS C:\git\myproject> cmd /c 'git stash show stash@{0}'
```

But IMHO it has too many additional keystrokes to make the switch worth it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought PowerShell could run almost all CMD commands?

Comment: @Ecstasy it can run any command, if you escape it properly. I am asking for a hint on how to make the escaping effort as small as possible. Run `cmd /c echo {}` from both `CMD` and `PowerShell` and you will see unwanted different results.

Comment: You will have to escape **where necessary**.

Comment: @DavidPostill you mean to prepend a backtick to these chars `(){}"'` ? Is that what PowerShell fans do?

Comment: I just found the `stop-processing` tag `--%`. Looks promising.

Comment: [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command line tools (and their weirdest parameters) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/josebda/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Powershell will run `git` and any other cmd-based functions without any issue if you quote parameters with special characters like so:

```
git stash show 'stash@{0}'
```

Much easier and cleaner.

Single quotes force everything to be literal, including escape characters. Double quotes will only parse and choke on `$`, used for variables. The quote characters themselves get parsed and removed so `git` never sees them unless manually escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I just found out the [stop-parsing symbol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) `--%`:

```
git --% stash show stash@{0}
```

> The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in PowerShell 3.0, directs
>   PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as PowerShell commands
>   or expressions.
>
> When calling an executable program in PowerShell, place the
>   stop-parsing symbol before the program arguments. This technique is
>   much easier than using escape characters to prevent misinterpretation.
>
> When it encounters a stop-parsing symbol, PowerShell treats the
>   remaining characters in the line as a literal. The only interpretation
>   it performs is to substitute values for environment variables that use
>   standard Windows notation, such as %USERPROFILE%.
>
> The stop-parsing symbol is effective only until the next newline or
>   pipeline character. You cannot use a continuation character (`) to
>   extend its effect or use a command delimiter (;) to terminate its
>   effect.